# sudo apt-get update causes troubles

Tags: updates

```
Hit:1 http://repo.steampowered.com/steam precise InRelease
Hit:2 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic InRelease                        
Hit:3 http://packages.microsoft.com/repos/vscode stable InRelease              
Hit:4 http://ppa.launchpad.net/graphics-drivers/ppa/ubuntu bionic InRelease    
Hit:5 https://deb.opera.com/opera-stable stable InRelease                      
/usr/bin/gdbus: error while loading shared libraries: libgio-2.0.so.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
appstreamcli: error while loading shared libraries: libappstream.so.4: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
Reading package lists... Done
E: Problem executing scripts APT::Update::Post-Invoke-Success 'if /usr/bin/test -w /var/cache/app-info -a -e /usr/bin/appstreamcli; then appstreamcli refresh-cache > /dev/null; fi'
E: Sub-process returned an error code
```

This is what I get now

Comment: @karel E: Unable to locate package libappstream3, This is what I get from sudo apt-get purge libappstream3

Comment: @karel Also, my software & update don't open, are these two errors connected? I'm suffering from this 3 days

Answer (score 0):

I got the same.  Resolved it with:

```
apt install libglib2.0-0
```